# Is there a list of all resolutions made by the Arab League?

Tags: political-history, historical-research, arab

I was interested in looking at all the resolutions that were made by the Arab League. I have found a [list of sessions](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/sessions-of-the-arab-league-1945-1994) made by the [Jewish Virtual Library](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org), however I was wondering if there is a compiled list, somewhere, listing all the resolutions taken?

Is it possible that the list above does actually include all approved resolutions, and the numbers assigned apply to each proposed resolution, hence the numbers jump frequently?

EDIT:

I have also found this [archived list](https://web.archive.org/web/20041114205235/http://faculty.winthrop.edu/haynese/MLAS/ALSessions.html) that does seem to match the list at JVL, probably the latter being based on this one.

Comment: Have you tried looking for one in Arabic? You might get luckier than searching for one in English.

Comment: The resolutions of the '67 summit can be found here: https://israeled.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/1967.9.1-Arab-League-Summit-Resolution1.pdf , but this is probably only the start point.

Answer (score 4):

This is by no means a complete answer, but is far too long for a comment.

---

### tl; dr

It does seem that there is no complete published list of the resolutions taken by the Arab League from its foundation in Cairo in June 1945.  The lists that are available have been compiled from various sources, some of which are now available online, and these are listed below.

---

### Sources

The preamble to the second list that you located (on Internet Archive's Wayback Machine) names five sources for the resolutions listed there:

- Robert W. Macdonald: [The League of Arab States, a study in the dynamics of regional organization](https://archive.org/details/leagueofarabstat0000macd/page/348), 1965
- Muhammad Khalil: [The Arab States and the Arab League: A Documentary Record](https://archive.org/details/arabstatesandthe012664mbp/page/n185), 1962
- The [Middle East Journal](https://www.jstor.org/journal/middeastj) 1947-
- The U.S. Foreign Broadcast Intelligence Service Daily Report.
- The Arab League Secretariat-General: *Majma’at Qararat Majlis Jami’at ad-Duwal al-Arabiyya*  -  ("Collection of the Resolutions of the Council of the League of Arab States"); covering resolutions from 4 June 1945 to 17 November 1957.

In addition to the above, a number of declassified documents are available from the CIA [Freedom of Information Act Electronic Reading Room](https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/).  I used the search term `Arab League` which returned 2088 documents, including - as an example - this [report, dated 24 January 1947 on the meeting of the Arab League](https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP82-00457R000300030008-1.pdf)

There does not appear to be a list of historical resolutions on the current website of [The League of Arab States](http://www.lasportal.org/ar/Pages/default.aspx)

---

In his book *The Arab States and the Arab League: A Documentary Record*, Muhammad Khalil included a list of the resolutions of the Arab League.  He did not claim that the list was complete, and included the following footnote about his sources:

> This resolution and the following resolutions have been translated by the Editor from the official (Arabic) texts of the resolutions as they appear in the Arab League's *Majmu'at Qararat Majlis Jami'at ad-Duwal al-Arabiyya* (Collection of the Resolutions of the Council of the League of Arab States) June 4, 1945 - November 17, 1957. The titles of, together with the references to these resolutions are verbatim translations of the respective official Arabic texts. Pagination refers to the relevant pages of the *Majmu'at* mentioned above. These resolutions dating after November 17, 1957 have been obtained privately in mimeographed form, from the Secretariat-General of the Arab-League ED

- Muhammad Khalil: The Arab States and the Arab League: A Documentary Record, p145

---

### Availability

The first two texts are available to read free from archive.org on the links provided above.

The *Middle East Journal* is published by the [Middle East Institute](https://www.mei.edu/education/middle-east-journal).  Back issues are available online free to subscribers.  Back issues are also available (from the first issue in January 1947 up to Volume 69 - 2015) from JSTOR on the link under 'Sources' above (free if you have a subscription that covers it, pay-per-view otherwise).

Copies of U.S. Foreign Broadcast Intelligence Service Daily Reports (and reports from successor agencies) are held with other CIA records at the US National Archives in the [collection RG263.3](https://www.archives.gov/research/guide-fed-records/groups/263.html#263.3).  It does not appear that they are yet available online.  However, some relevant reports may be available on the CIA FOIA Electronic Reading Room linked above.

I have not been able to find a copy of the document *Majma’at Qararat Majlis Jami’at ad-Duwal al-Arabiyya* online or available for purchase (although this may just be a reflection of my lack of Arabic language skills!).  However, you may be able to obtain a copy, or details of how to obtain a copy, by contacting the Secretariat of the Arab States directly.  Their contact details are on [their website](http://www.lasportal.org/ar/Pages/default.aspx).